# Am I using libGDX Asset Manager correctly?

Tags: libgdx, asset-management

My understanding is that you initialize the AssetManager as a non-static object in your main class and load the sprites you need...

```
    manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.load("sprite_sheet.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.finishLoading();
```

I then modified my abstract State class by adding AssetManager to the constructor...

```
 State(GameStateManager gsm, AssetManager manager) {
    this.gsm = gsm;
    this.manager = manager;
```

Now say I have 5 blocks in my sprite sheet called block0, block1... block5 would it be appropriate to create a BlockTextures class like this?

```
private static TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

public BlockTextures(AssetManager manager) {
    textureAtlas = manager.get("sprite_sheet.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
}

public static AtlasRegion get(int id) {
    return textureAtlas.findRegion("block" + id);
}

public static void dispose() {
    textureAtlas.dispose();
}
```

Where I call BlockTextures.dispose() in my Game.dispose() method?

```
public void dispose() {
    BlockTextures.dispose();
}
```

While this code seems to work fine I feel like I am not using AssetManager correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you certainly can do what you're doing I would suggest that you pass your `AssetManager` around yo the classes that need to load resources instead. So instead of doing `BlockTextures.get(id);` where you need to use the texture you should instead pass the `AssetManager` and do

```
// Store this variable 
TextureAtlas atlas = manager.get(name, TextureAtlas.class);

//Use the Atlas later as you would normally
atlas.whatever();
```

It is also **crucial** that you don't dispose individual assets using their `dispose` method. Instead dispose of the `AssetManager` or use the `unload` method of the `AssetManager` to unload a specific resource.

You can read more on AssetManager [on the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets).

Comment: If I get a Texture from an TextureAtlas which I got from AssetManager I don't dispose of the Texture even though it's twice removed from the AssetManager?

Comment: @java You either call `manager.unload(resource)` or `manager.dispose()`. You never call dispose on the actual resource.